# Telegram API - Отправка Emoji

Tags: telegram-bot

как отправлять emoji смайлики через API Telegram?

В [официальной документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) ни слово про смайликов. Где-то пишут, что нужно отправлять [`UTF-8` код смайлика.](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)...но все без толку

```
U+1F601
U1F601
#1F601;
&#1F601;
\xF0\x9F\x98\x81
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так покажите, как посылаете эти данные

Comment: как UTF коды, вместо смайликов (дополнил)

Comment: Попробуйте отослать в двойных кавычках следующую последовательность: `\xF0\x9F\x98\x81`

Comment: так тоже пытаслся, тоже не работает

Comment: А язык какой у вас?

Comment: я не использую язык... отправляю через программу заголовки(запрос)

Comment: Я клоню к тому, что напишите конкретный пример, как вы формируете заголовок и в какой программе

Comment: Обычный запрос, как сказано в документации API. Я дополнил

Comment: Не забыли ли вы закодировать текст? `%F0%9F%98%81`

Comment: ДА! Спасибо! Прошу вас перенести ваш комментарий в ответы и дополнить его, чтобы знать во что кодировать. Спасибо еще раз!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Добавил ответ

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Посмотрите на [Emoji Unicode Tables](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode).
Нужный вам код смайлика находится в колонке `Bytes (UTF-8)`.

Перед отправкой на сервер необходимо выполнять URL Encode.

Например, `\xF0\x9F\x98\x81` должен выглядеть так: `%F0%9F%98%81`.

Answer (score 4):

Я просто копировал emoji из [таблицы выше](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) обычным выделением мышкой (как выделяется текст) из колонки "Native" получается вот так:

Comment: Работает на node.js. Либо можно просто выбрать эмоджи на компьютере, если у тебя есть эмоджи клавиатура, и вставить в строку. Идеальный вариант, так как и в коде легко считывается

Answer (score 4):

На *bash* я использую [этот](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F601/index.htm) ресурс для получения кода

Строка "C/C++/Java source code" отображает необходимую кодировку.
Запрос приобретает вид

```
/usr/local/bin/curl -s --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --request 'POST' --data "{\"chat_id\":\"-432111111\",\"text\":\"\uD83D\uDC4C - Here is OK emoji\"}" "https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendMessage"
```

где `\uD83D\uDE31` и есть кодированный символ 👌

Answer (score 3):

Пишу бота на C#, работает в таком виде `"\U0001F69A"` для кода `U+1F69A` из таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

Для **РНР** там где смайл:

```
hex2bin('f09f9880')<br>
f09f9880
```

- **код смайла** без `\х` [отсюда](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) (колонка `Bytes (UTF-8)`)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте средства для представления Unicode текста в вашей среде. Она сама выполнит преобразование из текста в октеты согласно utf-8 кодировке, а затем произведёт [percent-encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1). Например, чтобы отправить флаг , который состоит из Unicode символов [U+1f1f7](https://codepoints.net/U+1f1f7), [U+1f1fa](https://codepoints.net/U+1f1fa) в [restclient в Emacs](https://github.com/pashky/restclient.el):

```
POST https://api.telegram.org/bot:token/sendMessage
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

chat_id=:chat-id&text=ура !
```

Это выполняет http POST запрос по указанному url (bot идентифицируемый по `:token` отправляет сообщение `ура !` в `:chat-id` чат).

На Питоне это может выглядеть как:

```py
import requests

requests.post(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage',
              dict(chat_id=chat_id, text='ура !'))
```

Видно, что нет необходимости руками кодировать строку в ascii-представление:

```py
'\u0443\u0440\u0430 \U0001f1f7\U0001f1fa!'
```

Питон автоматически кодирует сообщение. На сервер уходит (зашифрованное с помощью TLS), что-то вроде:

```py
POST /bot<token>/sendMessage HTTP/1.1
Host: api.telegram.org
User-Agent: python-requests/2.18.4
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 69
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

chat_id=<chat-id>&text=%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0+%F0%9F%87%B7%F0%9F%87%BA%21
```