# Отправка запроса боту telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot

У меня есть чат-бот для telegram, написанный на python. Необходимо протестировать работу бота, в связи с чем возникает вопрос как отправить запрос боту с помощью api или каким-либо другим способом. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не понятна суть вопроса, просто запустите бота и посылайте ему сообщения.

Comment: вот [пример отправки запроса telegram боту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/737200/23044)