# Как отправить сообщение/команду боту не из чата, а программно?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

С помощью декораторов можно отловить, например, определённую команду, посылаемую боту.
Например, если использовать такой декоратор:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['abc'])
def abc(message):
    .........
```

то, при отправке мной команды '/abc' боту из чата, он выполнит всё, что указанно в функции abc().

Вопрос такой, как без помощи чата (не используя приложение Telegram на телефоне/компьютере) отправить боту ту же команду '/abc', следовательно, что бы выполнился код функции abc()?

Используя, например, requests и т.д. для обращения к API Telegram

Comment: пример от бота в чат: [просто requests.post() вызовите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/737200/23044)

Comment: ??? вы, наверное, не поняли суть вопроса.

Comment: вы наверное комментарий не поняли ;)

Answer (score 1):

Схема работы бота - событийная, не используя телефон или другие клиенты можно только заставлять его отправлять сообщения и выполнять другие действия, перечень которых определён [*Bot API*](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api). Вклинить свой код туда вы не сможете. Свой код вы можете выполнять только ловя обновления ([*Updates*](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update)) от бота (любые).

**UPD**<sup>Чуть подробнее о том же самом</sup>

У бота, как программы, только одна точка входа - получение обновлений от серверов телеграма. То есть, если не придёт обновление (*команда боту, например*) - ваша логика его обработки не будет выполнена, ваш код не будет выполняться. Обновления можно слать **только клиентом** - официальными клиентами мессенджера (*только через интерфейс*), либо собственным клиентом на базе [*Telegram API*](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id) (*через интерфейс либо программно*).

Обращение к боту через Bot API позволяет выполнять только предопределённые действия, такие как [*sendMessage*](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage), [*sendInvoice*](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendinvoice) и тп. Никакой свой *middleware* выполнить не получится.

Соответственно, если хотите, чтобы выполнялся какой-то конкретный код по какой-то конкретной команде - эту **команду надо послать через одного из клиентов**, не имеет значения какого. Либо, как вариант, использовать выполнение какого-то куска кода по расписанию.

---

<sup>Не по теме вопроса непосредственно, но может быть полезно - [Пример отправки сообщения от бота напрямую http-запросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/547648/183842).</sup>

Comment: автор хочет не от бота сообщения посылать, а в обратную сторону (функция клиента telegram, реализуемая такими библиотеками как  [telephon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon): `client.send_message()`). Именно поэтому я ссылку выше [в виде комментария привёл](https://goo.gl/17Awcd), а не ответа (так как в обратную сторону пример).

Comment: Кнопка *"Отправить ответ"* добавляет не комментарий, а ответ. Если вы хотите добавить комментарий к вопросу, то нажмите на *"добавить комментарий"* кнопку вместо этого.

Comment: вы написали *"Я тоже привёл в виде комментария/дополнения."* и *"я отправил ответ"* -- вы определитесь: вы ответ хотели дать или всё-таки комментарий? Если это ответ, а не комментарий, то **ваш ответ неверен** (не описано "как отправить боту сообщение" -- обратите внимание не *от* бота, а боту (снаружи) -- внутреннее устройство бота никакого отношения к вопросу не имеет)

Comment: ответ неверен, потому что сообщение боту можно послать **извне** (вы понимаете, что клиент телеграмм не является частью бота, можно написать Питон-скрипт, который может посылать сообщения, не являясь ботом. Посмотрите на telephon модуль упомянутый в самом первом комментарии)¶ По поводу, *"А если даже и не был бы верен, то вас это как касается?"* -- вы думаете зачем на сайте голосование, комментарии есть? Зачем вообще ответы публикуются? Лично я только благодарен, если кто-то в моём коде ошибку найдёт. Это улучшает сайт, помогает будущим посетителям (95% траффика на SO из поиска приходит).